# Getting Enumeration yielded no results error although query works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a LINQ query like this :

```
var query = (from c in entities.Contents
                         join m in entities.Moderations on c.ModId equals m.ModId
                         join mac in entities.ModActionCategories on c.ActionCategoryId equals mac.ActionCategoryId 
                         where mac.WillAlert == true
                         select new DetailedContent
                         {
                             ActionCategoryId = c.ActionCategoryId,
                             ModId = c.ModId,
                             ContentSeqNum = c.ContentSeqNum,
                             ModTitle = m.ModerationTitle
                         }
                        );
return query.ToList();
```

When I execute it, it gives "Enumeration yielded no results" error. What's quite interesting is, actually query finds some entries. When I hover the `query` and copy/paste the generated SQL query to MS SQL, it gives correct results. What would be the possible reason?

Comment: It could possibly executing against the wrong database.

Comment: I double checked if that's the case, but I'm using the same entities as the others.

Comment: You could run SQL profiler and view the actual query executed against the database to verify whether it is the same as the one you get on hover?

Comment: Yes I checked, they are the same...

Comment: if (query.Any())
{}could u try this

Comment: At what line? Before return?

Comment: yes before return and pls check if it run the if statement

Comment: It runs the if statement and returns false.

Comment: so query.Any() return false so ,I guess , some parameter of your query return null.may be c.ActionCategoryId or boolean value